# WebSocket disconnects when debugging Uno-platform WebAssembly project

Tags: webassembly, uno-platform

I'm new to Uno-Platform (and, in general, debugging in Chrome). I'm having trouble getting Chrome to debug my Uno-Platform WASM project. I followed the instructions here,(https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/master/doc/articles/debugging-wasm.md/) but I keep getting this popup:
[Chrome WebSocket disconnected message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cZwD.png)

When I click on the "Reconnect DevTools" button, the popup displays again. I suspect it's something simple that I'm doing wrong.

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The [debugging story for .NET on WebAssembly is evolving very quickly](https://platform.uno/blog/debugging-uno-platform-webassembly-apps-in-visual-studio-2019/) lately, and the Visual Studio and .NET team have included preview support for it in 2019 16.6 Preview 1 and up.

The documentation is not yet up to date in the Uno repo, but to use it with Uno, you'll [have to do this](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap#upgrading-from-previous-versions-of-the-unowasmbootstrap-package) in your Wasm project file:

- If you had a `<DotNetCliToolReference />` line remove it
- Add a nuget reference to `Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.DevServer` prerelease package
- Update `Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap` to the same prerelease version as DevServer

Then [update the `launchSettings.json` file](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap#how-to-use-the-visual-studio-2019-debugger), add the following line just after each `"launchBrowser": true,` line :

```
"inspectUri":
  "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
```

You should be able to debug with a more stable experience inside of Visual Studio, but note that the debugging support is still in preview and you may still encounter issues.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was fixed by using the version `1.3.4` of the `Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap` and `Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.DevServer` NuGet-packages, instead of the newer versions.